# Wrong available storage reported for mac os

Tags: macos, storage, du, df

The available space on my Macbook Air is not getting reported correctly.

Hard disk capacity is 120GB out of which 17GB is getting reported as available space when I check HD info.

[image: Hard Disk capacity is 120GB with ~17GB free]

When I see in finder, I can see listing of folders with used space totalling to about 73GB.

So I wanted to know which folders are using the missing 29GB.

[image]

I hoped to find the missing data from command line. I ran `du -h -d 1` from the root folder, and it reported total 88 GB in use.

[image]

When i run `df -h` I get size of the disk as 112Gi, used space as 96Gi and Available space as 16Gi.

[image]

So I see that although `df` reports used space of 96GB, `du` only lists usage of 88GB.

I want to know which folders are occupying the unaccounted space.

Comment: You title has nothing to do with your issue. Memory & Storage/disk space are entirely different things. Your ref to "folders/processes" as though they were complementary things further adds to the confusion, as does the tag of 'memory leak'.

Answer (score 0):

For `df`, take a look at `man df`:

```
 -H      "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte
         and Petabyte in order to reduce the number of digits to three or less using base 10 for
         sizes.

 -h      "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte
         and Petabyte in order to reduce the number of digits to three or less using base 2 for
         sizes.
```

You used `-h`, which uses base 2 sizes. The Finder is reporting base 10 sizes.

Check the output of `df -H` — you'll find that it matches what the Finder says exactly.